# Docker Image Run Issue: cat: command not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While trying to run a docker image. I am getting the following error.

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 46: cat: command not found`

Am I missing something to add to the image while building it? What could be the issue?

Here is the Dockerfile

````
FROM scratch
# new image
LABEL docker-slim.version=linux|Transformer|1.36.4|8e0e0a59720bb95c708c046cf9ec71b4939803da|2021-09-07_08:07:15AM
ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7
ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7
ENV MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.17-1debian8
VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]
ADD file:931d8c01612b2bf01443d3141de5c0899c7346c0167a9dc0c1da3ec194a0665c /
EXPOSE 3306/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
# end of image:  (id:  tags: )```
````

Comment: What is in the file you `ADD`?

Comment: scratch is an empty image. Perhaps you should use busybox instead which provides all the basic utilities and has a very small footprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FROM scratch` means 'start from an empty directory'. There is no `cat` inside, unless explicitly added it. One way to do that is to copy the binary from another image:

```
FROM debian:buster as cat_source
FROM scratch
COPY --from=cat_source /bin/cat /bin/cat
# the rest of the dockerfile
...
```